# Annotation Authentication with Session

Tags: java, jersey, guice, embedded-jetty

I Started using Guice for my project, but i'm stuck re-implementing the Authentication Interceptor that worked so well using Jersey only.

My old code gave me access to both The ResourceInfo and the HttpServletRequest doing the following:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest webRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        // Resource, Which gives me the Target Function (From here i can check annotations)
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();

        // User object in the session, which contains a list of permissions
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity) webRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user");

        // DO auth....

    }
}
```

Sadly, when attempting to use this interface in Guice i'm not getting any context
(resourceInfo and webRequests stays null)

I have made attempts with javax.servlet.filter, but i cannot seem to get access to the **Target method**

My Guice configuration is:

```
 @Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(DebugController.class).in(Singleton.class);

    bind(MessageBodyReader.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    bind(MessageBodyWriter.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);


    HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    serve("/api/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, options);
}
```

Edit:
Ive also tried to use

```
    public class AuthorisationInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

            // Allow invocation to process or throw an appropriate exception
        }
}
```

but i funny enough i have no access to the Session.

So my question is this: How can i manage Authentication using Guice as the interceptor?
My requirements are that i have access to the **Session** and the **Target Resource**?

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is your interceptor annotated as @Provider?

Comment: A desperate attempt to get that class to work. Sorry, ignore it.

Comment: How are you telling Guice to inject your authenticator?

Comment: My Authenticator is simply looking up the Session object and the Method Annotation.

When a user is not logged in, the Session attribute "user" will be null, which will redirect to login. If the the session attribute is set its evaluated if the user has enough permission.

I just managed to access a HTTP session from "MethodInterceptor" But the Session is not the same as in my Resources. I did the following

`public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Inject
    private Provider<HttpSession> sessionProvider;
}`


This gave me "something" but the wrong session